# How to keep DOMNode::cloneNode() from inserting redundant namespaces?

Tags: php, xml, dom, xml-namespaces

I'm using PHP's [built-in DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) implementation to modify an XML document, specifically the `content.xml` file in an ODS spreadsheet. This document makes heavy use of namespaces (35 different namespaces are declared in the root element).

I'm trying to copy a `table-cell` element to a new row using shallow [cloneNode()](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.clonenode.php), but the result is not exactly identical to the original:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<office:document-content
    xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0"
    xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0"
    xmlns:calcext="urn:org:documentfoundation:names:experimental:calc:xmlns:calcext:1.0"
    [... snip 32 ...]>

<!-- original -->
<table:table-cell table:style-name="ce5"
                  office:value-type="string"
                  calcext:value-type="string">

<!-- cloned -->
<table:table-cell xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0"
                  xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0"
                  xmlns:calcext="urn:org:documentfoundation:names:experimental:calc:xmlns:calcext:1.0"
                  table:style-name="ce5"
                  office:value-type="string"
                  calcext:value-type="string">
```

While this is semantically similar, it can cause major bloat in larger spreadsheets (even though the XML is zipped on disk).

Is there a solution to this?

---

The naive approach of using the non-namespace aware methods, and simply copying the attributes (including prefix and tag name), appears to works, at first:

```
$clone = $doc->createElement($ele->tagName);
foreach ($ele->attributes as $att) {
    $clone->setAttribute($att->nodeName, $att->value);
}
```

The resulting XML looks exactly as intended. But when the cloned element is manipulated again:

```
$clone->setAttributeNS($officeNS, "office:value-type", "string");
```

the result has **two identical** attribute names:

```
<table:table-cell xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0"
                  table:style-name="ce5"
                  office:value-type="string"
                  calcext:value-type="string"
                  office:value-type="string"
                  office:string-value="">
```

which makes the document invalid. In general, I found it unpracticable to mix namespaced and non-namespaced method calls.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an libxml constant that allows to optimize the namespaces on loading:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<f:foo xmlns:f="urn:foo">
  <f:foo>
    <f:foo xmlns:f="urn:foo">
    </f:foo>
  </f:foo>
</f:foo>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml, LIBXML_NSCLEAN);
echo $document->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<f:foo xmlns:f="urn:foo">
  <f:foo>
    <f:foo>
    </f:foo>
  </f:foo>
</f:foo>
```

This works mostly, but I got some invalid results if the same prefix is used for different namespaces in the same document.

The [FluentDOM](https://github.com/FluentDOM/FluentDOM/blob/master/examples/transformer/namespaces/optimize.php) library contains an optimizer for this job. It allows you to change/define the prefixes, too.